# Error while integrating sonar maven - fxcop and source monitor plugins

Tags: .net, maven, sonarqube, binaries

I installed Maven, Sonar and the respective plugins for .net projects. I am able to build my project using Maven too.
When i run, `mvn dotnet:compile` - build success
Similarly, `coverage, cpd, clean, package, unpack` succeed too.

But, when i run `mvn dotnet:fxcop` and `mvn dotnet:metrics` then build fails.
The error message reads -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.dotnet:maven-dotnet-pl
ugin:0.5:fxcop (default-cli) on project ComplaintManagementSystem: FxCop binarie
s were not found  

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.dotnet:maven-dotnet-pl
ugin:0.5:metrics (default-cli) on project ComplaintManagementSystem: SourceMonit
or binaries were not found
```

I am able to analyze project using fxcop and SourceMonitor using fxcop and SourceMonitor tools.

How can i resolve this error? Is this a configuration issue? SHould I make any changes to the pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The integration for .NET projects in Sonar has eveolved a lot. The plugins are now in version 1.3 and they do not require Maven anymore.

You can check the documentation and examples on our Wiki: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C-Sharp+Plugins+Ecosystem

Answer (score 0):

As Fabrice said, the maven dotnet plugin is no more mandatory to run suonar. However if you want to use this plugin to dun theses tools, the only things thta is missing is a a couple of configuration properties specifying where to find the binaries of FxCop and SourceMonitor. For more details see below the settings.xml example : http://maven-dotnet-plugin.appspot.com/settings.html

Hope it helps